# How to redirect to another page by clicking on image

Tags: java, image, servlets, onclick

```
package com.system.servlets;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Redirect
 */
@WebServlet("/Redirect")
public class Redirect extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
     */
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    System.out.println("servlet is intialized");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");  
        ServletOutputStream out;  
        out = response.getOutputStream();  
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("/home/mpatil/Desktop/Ram/downloads/gmail image.jpg");  

        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);  
        BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(out);  
        int ch =0; ;  
        while((ch=bin.read())!=-1)  
        {  
        bout.write(ch);  
        }  

        bin.close();  
        fin.close();  
        bout.close();  
        out.close();    

    }



}
```

This is my servlets program,it would  showing gmail image.Now my question is if i click on gmail image then it redirect to gmail login page.Is there any possible in Servlets ?What are the changes in my program.?give me suggestion for my case.Good answers will always appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do what you want to do in the way you have tried. Here you are sending the image in the stream. What you have to do is send a HTML page which has a link to image and have that image inside href tag which directs to google login. (as following)

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="link to page where you want it to go on click"><img src="path to your image"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

open a notepad or any text editor copy above html as required and save it as a jsp with required file name.

Comment: i tried using html for to display image but am not get desire out put. That's y i went to stream.Can u say how to go through HTML in servlets.can u provide that steps pls...

Comment: Remove all the code inside your doGet method and add the following code. `code`request.getRequestDispatcher("/myhtml.jsp").forward(request, response);  `code` . Then write you all html there in that "myhtml.jsp" file.

Comment: `request.getRequestDispatcher("/myhtml.jsp").forward(request, response);` how to create jsp file i mean this JSP file is creating inside my program or some where.can u suggest me pls........

Comment: You should read a book, [link](http://books.google.lk/books?id=HwBEBrMIh5IC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false) this will cover everything you need.

Comment: how to create jsp file i mean this JSP file is creating inside my program or some where.can u suggest me pls.

Comment: First read a book and understand what jsp and servlets are and how web apps work. Then you will know.

Comment: i have no time to read this book.please tel me how to write jsp file or just give code pls pls

Comment: Thanq.How to create jsp file in program? i mean this jsp file how to create in program can u tel me that or just edit my question or just give code for case....pls pls pls

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="Redirect"><img src="gmail.gif"></a>
```

Comment: `<a href="http://localhost:<port>/<app_context>/Redirect"><img src="gmail.gif"></a>` should work.